# Linux Bash grep extract word from matching string

Tags: regex, grep, pcre

I have numbers starging with a special character `@` and ending with `900` and I now I want to extract the text in between excluding them.
My code:

```
>> cat demo.txt
asdfsdf
@ 1234900 asdf dfasd
asdf @ 1345900-asdfad wer
@ 678900-asdfa adf 

>> grep -Po '@\K.*900' demo.txt
1234900
1345900
678900
```

Expected answer:

```
1234
1345
678
```

Comment: `'@\s\K\d*(?=900)'` instead. Use a lookahead so the 900 isn't part of the matched text.

Comment: @Shawn yes this solved like cham. I just started learning `bash` on `linux` a couple of days ago. I know `@*900` how this works but can you help me how `\K.` and `(?=900)` works. Thanks

Comment: `\K` is like a positive lookbehind; the pattern before it must match, but the text it matches isn't part of the final overall matched text.

Comment: `grep -Po '[0-9]+(?=900)' file`?

Comment: @Cyrus Yes! this also worked and produced the desired result. Please, can you explain how the `[0-9]+(?=)` works here. Thanks

Comment: `how the [0-9]+(?=) works here` Perl regex is quite advanced https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre and https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html . For starters, start with normal regex, i recommend with regex crosswords.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```sh
grep -oP '@\s*\K\d+?(?=900)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VyBWSg/1/). *Details*:

- `-o` - the option makes `grep` output all matched substrings rather than lines where a match occurred
- `P` - enables the PCRE regex engine rather than the default POSIX BRE
- `@` - a `@` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `\d+?` - one or more digits, as few as possible
- `(?=900)` - until the first, leftmost, occurrence of `900` char sequence.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/jB5ABs):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='asdfsdf
@ 1234900 asdf dfasd
asdf @ 1345900-asdfad wer
@ 678900-asdfa adf '
grep -oP '@\s*\K\d+?(?=900)' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
1234
1345
678
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am beginner and this helps me a lot. Also, what does `-oP` does? Thanks

Comment: @Mainland I added the description to "Details".